# how to bind four tables in single datagridview wpf linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have single datagridview and I want to bind it with four tables connected 
with each other and the photo explains the relations
[relations of four tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDUNF.png)

I tried to bind it with wpf but I couldn't
my code of loadData is:

```
 CollegeContext cd = new CollegeContext(); 

 var query = (from sc in cd.StudentStatments

     join l in cd.Levels on sc.IdLevel equals l.Id
     join b in cd.Branches on sc.IdBranch equals b.Id
     join su in cd.Subjects on sc.IdSubject equals su.Id

     select new DGItem
     {
          NameSub = su.Name,
          TypeOfBranch = b.TypeOfBranch,
          Code = su.Code,
          NameLev=l.Name,
          NumOfStudent = sc.NumberOfStudent
      }).ToList();
      studentStatmentsDataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
```

and my xaml is :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="studentStatmentsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="128,284,0,0" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Subject.Name}" Header="NameSubjects" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding TypeOfBranch}" Header=" Branch" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Code}" Header=" code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Levels.Name}" Header=" Level" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding NumberOfStudent}" Header="NumberOfStudent" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and my user control resources :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="1">#FF3580BF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Color1">#FFECE3E3</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Color2">#FF3580BF</Color>
    <Astmara6:Branches x:Key="branches"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="branchesViewSource" Source="{Binding _Branches, Source={StaticResource branches}}"/>
    <Astmara6:Section x:Key="section"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="sectionsViewSource" Source="{Binding Sections, Source={StaticResource section}}"/>
    <Astmara6:Levels x:Key="levels"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="levelsViewSource" Source="{Binding _Levels, Source={StaticResource levels}}"/>
    <Astmara6:Subjects x:Key="subjects"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="subjectsViewSource" Source="{Binding _Subjects, Source={StaticResource subjects}}"/>
    <Astmara6:TeachSubBranch x:Key="teachSubBranch"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="subjectsViewSource1" Source="{Binding Subjects, Source={StaticResource teachSubBranch}}"/>
    <Astmara6:StudentStatment x:Key="studentStatment"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="studentStatmentsViewSource" Source="{Binding StudentStatments, Source={StaticResource studentStatment}}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I expect to show  su.Name  ,  b.TypeOfBranch ,su.Code ,l.Name, sc.NumberOfStudent in my datagridview but it doesn't appear all data

Answer (score 0):

With setting ItemsSource={Binding} you are binding it to the DataGrid.DataContext. This Binding is still active when you set the value in code - so ItemsSource is always pointing to DataContext, which i assume is empty.

You have two Options to go:
Either remove the ItemsSource Binding from your DataGrid in xaml
 or 
set the DataContex instead of the ItemsSource in code behind.